# How can I hide an id from its contents in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I have a bunch of this videos on this website with this source:

```
<li id="vidLink-1498229769" class="videoContainer vidLink">
    <a href="/p/watch/1498229769:GM1ryG4eoTA6sMZV9wtDEpocuehpzDni">
        <span class="content-video-thumb-hover"></span>
        <img src="http://lockerz.vo.llnwd.net/o35/Lockerz/14/593/MEVIO-EmoGirlTV-SavesTheDay-TH1.jpg" id="clThumb_1498229769" class="videoThumb">
    </a>
    <a href="/p/watch/1498229769:GM1ryG4eoTA6sMZV9wtDEpocuehpzDni" class="videoTitle">Emo Girl TV - Saves the Day Interview</a>
                    <span class="PTZ-status PTZ-awarded">PTZ have been awarded for watching this video.</span>
```

Is it possible to hide the entire id, the vidlink-*** part if the span class is that?

```
<span class="PTZ-status PTZ-awarded">PTZ have been awarded for watching this video.</span>
```

I want to hide the videos I've already seen in the site (with greasemonkey), but I have no idea how...

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it is... but I am not clear on what you want to hide and when.

Comment: The entire vidlink, the entire class/form or whatever it is... I have many classes like this one, all from different videos, and I want to hide the ones I already have saw

Comment: How can you tell whether you already saw it?

Comment: Slakz, "PTZ-status PTZ-awarded", the awarded means I've already saw... I've change your command to ptz-awarded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to hide the entire `vidLink` if it contains a `.PTZ-status`, you can do it like this:

```
$('.vidLink:has(.PTZ-awarded)').hide();
```

Comment: worked good, but when I change the page, the others shows up, guess it's because greasemonkey dont reload like the page... how can I solve this putting all videos in the same page? I have this in the source <input type="hidden" value="12" id="vid_count">
<input type="hidden" value="422" id="vid_max">
<input type="hidden" value="12" id="vids_per_page">

Comment: This line only hides the elements that currently exist.  You need to execute the code again each time the page changes.

Comment: can't I add some command to change the max videos on the page to like, 100000, so it would be everything only in one page?

Comment: the video page... it contains that 3 input types, that I think is my intent